# Error while running KCL consumer with the localstack Kinesis

Tags: netty, http2, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, localstack

Caught exception while syncing Kinesis shards and leases

Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 3c21444f43

Comment: There are a number of environment variables to set and correct framework choices (eg KCL version) to get this working with localstack. You need to post more info regards your setup and how you run it, eg docker compose file for example. As a first step make sure you have enabled localstack logging and post the logging  error trace

Comment: @NigelSavage this issue was resolved by using the younger version of this library. This issue occurs with NodeJS library and C# library. Java library works perfect as I understand. I am very upset that they no longer support these libraries